# Monads - map function with multiple input parameters

Tags: functional-programming, monads

I'm learning functional programming and I am confused by some contradictory information I found about monads. As I can't get it straight, I decided to ask (to be clear, I'm not learning Haskell or any specific FP language, actually I'm practicing in C++, so I'm looking to the most language-agnostic solutions).

Let A, B and C be types, and M and N be monads. Let f:A->? be an application.

**First doubt**: should the application be `f:A->B`, or `f:A->M B`?

Just to mention two contradictory sources, Philipp Hagenlocher in his *Haskell for Imperative Programmers* online tutorial requires f:A->M B, while Ivan Cukic's book Functional Programming in C++ requires f:A->B. Wikipedia distinguishes between the join ( `fmap :: (a -> b) -> M a -> M b` ) and the bind ( `bind :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b` ) but does not specify which one is required for monads (join, bind, or both?)

This is far from being a trivial issue, as the f:A->B requirement allows to lift any function to use Monads, while f:A->M B requires to change the function to specifically factor in the monad used.

Also, in the f:A->B case, the responsibility to provide a proper input lies on the monad M a, while in the f:A->M B, the responsibility to check the input is on the function itself.

**second doubt**: suppose parameters A a and B b need to be contained into monads (such as the Maybe a and Maybe b) and you have the application f:a,b->c. How do you handle that? Especially if you want to do partial applications?

My first hypothesis is to create "a monad in a monad" (I don't know how to say it in a more formal way).

`bind(bind(f(a,x), M a), M b)->M c`

I'm not really convinced about that. For it to work, the bind function must return a function with the monadic logic in it, as the first parameter of the bind function is an application. But by definition the bind function returns a Monad, not an application.

My second guess is to create a monad that contains both parameters, such as N [a,b] with [] denoting a vector, so that the function becomes

`bind(f(a,b), N [a,b]) -> M c`

That could work, but in my limited experience I've never seen a monad joining two monads.

Comment: by putting your code snippets between backticks `\``, you could help improve legibility of your text.

Comment: You can already lift `a -> b` with functor. If you want to combine several functors you can use the applicative operation. Monad requires actions of type `a -> M b`, because they encode the idea of effects (not side effects) that depend on values of a previous monadic computation. Btw, you can simply compose a pure function with the monadic `return` operation to transform `a -> b` into `a -> M b`.

Comment: @bob I believe that my doubt is: the transformation from `a -> b` into `a -> M b` (for example, in C++ composing the function with a `try {...} catch (Exception e){return Nothing;} return JustResult;`) is the responsibility of the Monad, or of the application? Because the mathematical definition of the Monad only states that it must be an endofunctor with a map application. From what you said, it seems the responsibility lies on the application and the monad remains "clean", is that correct? Can you post it as an answer so I upvote it?

Comment: There is no implicit transformation from pure functions `a -> b` to actions `a -> M b` within a monadic computation. However, you can reuse pure functions by explicitly transforming them into actions by composing them with `return`. A monad with the `bind` operator encodes a way to apply an action `a -> M b` to values `M a` in an effectful context represented by `M`. So it is all about function application in the presence of effects, where functions are actions and return an effectful value themselves.